# how can I train the model to predict duplicate records in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, record-linkage

I have the adjustment data in telecom domain:
There are problems that sometimes the automation script generates the bill twice which causes duplicate records.

I want to know how to prepare the data and train the ML model. 
Currently, I am considering the duplicate record as issues and training the SVM model for one-class classification.

```
Duplicate Bill
    ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
```

Should I train the model with actual bill and duplicate bill as both issues and train the model and then predict the rest or is there any other way to consider or should I implement time-series classification?

```
Records 
Actual Bill                                                     label
ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
Duplicate Bill
ABC13C,13.59,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,2017-03-01,118,I,A,0,C,2011    1
```

Comment: Why don't you just check for duplicates with DISTINCT in sql, or just compare the id's or something? What should your algoritm predict, based on what?

Comment: I have millions of records to check some time amount will be different

Comment: sometime they will be legitimate transaction which is being adjusted for the previous months

Answer (score 2):

There are packages available in R and Python which can help you with de-duplicating.

Python record linkage -> http://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html

R record linkage -> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html

Also refer to 
[Deep Learning approaches for Record Linkage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327864/deep-learning-approaches-for-record-linkage)